# Display first parent on the first child and the rest of the children with the same parent display as NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables, Parents and Children in SQL Server.

Parent Table

```
ParentID    ParentName
----------- ------------------
1           Parent 1
2           Parent 2
3           Parent 3
4           Parent 4
5           Parent 5
```

Children Table

```
ChildID     ChildName                           ParentID
----------- ----------------------------------- -----------
1           Child 1                             1
2           Child 2                             1
3           Child 3                             1
4           Child 4                             1
5           Child 5                             2
6           Child 6                             2
7           Child 7                             3
8           Child 8                             3
9           Child 9                             3
```

How can I query to display first parent on the first child and the rest of the children with the same parent display as NULL?

```
ChildID     ChildName                   ParentName
----------- --------------------------- -----------------
1           Child 1                     Parent 1
2           Child 2                     NULL
3           Child 3                     NULL
4           Child 4                     NULL
5           Child 5                     Parent 2
6           Child 6                     NULL
7           Child 7                     Parent 3
8           Child 8                     NULL
9           Child 9                     NULL
```

Comment: Just a small remark: This really smells like something which is usually dealt with in front end. Try to avoid losing yourself in data formatting on SQL Server whenever you can.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 is no longer supported. All supported versions have a [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) type that makes defining hierarchies and finding parents a *lot* simpler. It's time you upgraded to a supported version. BTW SQL Server 2016 SP1 provides in-memory tables, compression, columnstores, partitioning even in the Express and LocalDB editions. The performance, hardware  and licensing savings alone should justify the migration

Comment: I have a business requirement to generate a report that looks like this.
Thank you for your advice. I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query.

```
SELECT c.ChildId, c.ChildName, p.ParentName    
FROM    (SELECT childId, 
            ChildName, 
            ParentId, 
            Row_number() over(partition by ParentId Order by ParentId asc, ChildID asc) row_num
    FROM Children) c    
LEFT JOIN Parent p 
 ON c.ParentId = p.ParentId
  AND c.row_num = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as 
  (
  select  childId, 
            ChildName, ParentName,
            p.ParentId, Row_number() over(partition by p.ParentId Order by p.ParentId asc, ChildID asc) row_num  
  from Table20 a join parent p on a.ParentID=p.ParentID
  )
  select  childId, 
            ChildName, 
              CASE row_num WHEN 1 THEN ParentName ELSE NULL END as parentname from cte
```

output

```
childId ChildName   parentname
1   Child 1 Parent 1
2   Child 2 NULL
3   Child 3 NULL
4   Child 4 NULL
5   Child 5 Parent 2
6   Child 6 NULL
7   Child 7 Parent 3
8   Child 8 NULL
9   Child 9 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.*
      ,IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.[ParenetID] ORDER BY C.[ChildID]) <> 1, NULL, P.[ParentName])
FROM @Children C
INNER JOIN @Parent P
    ON C.[ParenetID] = P.[ParenetID]
```

Full working example:

```
DECLARE @Parent  TABLE
(
    [ParenetID] TINYINT
   ,[ParentName] VARCHAR(12)
);


DECLARE @Children  TABLE
(
    [ChildID] TINYINT
   ,[ChildName] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[ParenetID] TINYINT
);


INSERT INTO @Parent ([ParenetID], [ParentName])
VALUES   (1, 'Parent 1')
        ,(2, 'Parent 2')
        ,(3, 'Parent 3')
        ,(4, 'Parent 4')
        ,(5, 'Parent 5');

INSERT INTO @Children ([ChildID], [ChildName], [ParenetID])
VALUES   (1, 'Child 1', 1)
        ,(2, 'Child 2', 1)
        ,(3, 'Child 3', 1)
        ,(4, 'Child 4', 1)
        ,(5, 'Child 5', 2)
        ,(6, 'Child 6', 2)
        ,(7, 'Child 7', 3)
        ,(8, 'Child 8', 3)
        ,(9, 'Child 9', 3);

SELECT C.*
      ,IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.[ParenetID] ORDER BY C.[ChildID]) <> 1, NULL, P.[ParentName])
FROM @Children C
INNER JOIN @Parent P
    ON C.[ParenetID] = P.[ParenetID]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT c.ChildId, c.ChildName, CASE row_num WHEN 1 THEN p.ParentName ELSE NULL END    
(SELECT childId, ChildName, ParentId, 
        Row_number() over(partition by ParentId Order by ParentId asc, ChildID asc) row_num
FROM Children) c    
JOIN Parent p ON c.ParentId = p.ParentId
```